# R Default bookdown template not working for bookdown::pdf_book()

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

**My Problem**

I've been using seamlessly R's `bookdown` for a couple of weeks now until I've encountered ***the following error*** when running it's default template (skeleton) in RStudio:

```r
output file: _main.knit.md

! Paragraph ended before \MT@prot@l was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.141 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::pdf_book'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

**My Initial Diagnosis**

1. *The html version* `bookdown::gitbook()` *is still working!* When I commented-out as follows the `bookdown::pdf_book()` portion in the `_output.yml` file, the book rendered with all the LaTeX equations. Moreover, `bookdown::epub_book()` still also works.

   ```
   bookdown::gitbook:
     css: style.css
     config:
       toc:
         before: |
           <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
         after: |
           <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
       edit: https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/edit/BRANCH/%s
   #   download: ["pdf", "epub"]
   # bookdown::pdf_book:
   #   includes:
   #     in_header: preamble.tex
   #   latex_engine: xelatex
   #   citation_package: natbib
   #   keep_tex: yes
   # bookdown::epub_book: default
   ```
2. *I have resintalled RStudio, R, Rtools (with path included) TinyTex  and updated everything as suggested in https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging but still of no avail*.

**My `_main.log` File**

For reference, my `_main.log` file is here: https://github.com/rvcuenca/default_bookdown_template/blob/main/_main.log

**My `sessionInfo()`**

```r
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.36.9      magrittr_2.0.1    usethis_2.1.5     gert_1.4.3       
 [6] R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.12      fastmap_1.1.0     fansi_0.5.0       httr_1.4.2       
[11] tools_4.1.2       sys_3.4           xfun_0.28.10      utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.1.0        
[16] withr_2.4.3       gitcreds_0.1.1    htmltools_0.5.2   askpass_1.1       ellipsis_0.3.2   
[21] rprojroot_2.0.2   openssl_1.4.5     yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.29     tibble_3.1.6     
[26] lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.4.2      bookdown_0.24.4   purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.3.8      
[31] fs_1.5.2          credentials_1.3.2 curl_4.3.2        glue_1.5.1        evaluate_0.14    
[36] rmarkdown_2.11.3  gh_1.3.0          pillar_1.6.4      compiler_4.1.2    jsonlite_1.7.2   
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

**My Question**

Any thoughts where could have I went wrong?

Comment: try `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` in the console.

Comment: @TarJae, wow, i don't  know what happened but it did solve the problem for the template. I've tried this before when I reinstalled TinyTex or maybe i've missed something.  However, when I tried to run for another bookdown file this error popped-up:

```Output created: docs/index.html
Error in basename(files) : a character vector argument expected
Calls: local ... <Anonymous> -> source_files -> grep -> is.factor -> basename
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::pdf_book'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: @TarJae, i've fixed the second problem of mind. I've followed through from this link: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-building-a-book/68351. Thank you

Comment: This is a bug in a LaTeX package, which should be fixed soon: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/347 Try to run `tinytex::tlmgr_update()` tomorrow to update the `microtype` LaTeX package.

Comment: Glad to hear this good news @Yihui. tnx. After i've resolved the second issue, another issue popped-up: ```! Package keyval Error: style undefined.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::pdf_book'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.```

The cause is knitr options ```out.extra='style="display: inline-block; float: left; padding: 5px;"'``` in one of my images when I render it using `pdf_book()`

Comment: This new error sounds unfamiliar to me. I have no idea this time. Sorry.